# Storing large matrices in Apache Ignite

Tags: matrix, key-value, ignite

I have a large matrix of integers that I want to be able to slice and run analytics on. I'm prototyping this with Apache Ignite.

The matrix is 50000 columns x 5 million rows. I want to be able to run the following operations on this matrix:

1. Fetch all data for a single column
2. Fetch all data for some random subset of rows and columns.
3. Compute a correlation coefficient for one row against every other row.

I'm trying to satisfy 1. and 2. right now, but I can't figure out how to store a matrix. I was thinking of storing the matrix like this:

```
row1 {
    co1: val
    co2: val
    co3: val
    ...
    co50000: val
}
row2{ ... }
```

But I'm not sure if I can have complex data types like this in Ignite, or if I can only have a single key:value pair. The documentation is not clear. When I try to insert a dictionary using pyignite (my Java is a little rusty, so I'm sticking to python right now), the data comes back as an array:

```
>>> test.put('row2', { "col1": 50, "col2":0 })
>>> test.get('cell2')
['gene1', 'gene2']
```

I'm new to Apache Ignite, but the documentation doesn't seem to detail how to do this, or if it would even be performant.

Comment: As it is a matrix of integers, I'd probably use an integer as a key and an array of integers as a value, as it would take less memory. Note that by default Ignite stores data off-heap as an array of bytes and value is deserialised each time you access it. To avoid deserialisation you could use on-heap cache mode https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration#section-on-heap-caching. From the code snippet you provided it is not clear what you want to achieve and what is wrong.

Comment: I need to be able to specify certain values within the columns - I need to request row1, row50, row600 as well as col1, col50000, and col6. Storing the entire array won't work in that case, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to store 5 million KV pairs using row as key and containing  50000 columns array as value.

Better stick to primitive types. Not sure how to map it best to Python.

Comment: I need to be able to specify certain values within the columns - I need to request row1, row50, row600 as well as col1, col50000, and col6. Storing the entire array won't work in that case, right?

Comment: Why, fetch the whole row, get column that you need.

Comment: How can I specify the columns if the data is stored in an array?

Comment: `cache.get(row)[column]`?

Comment: I'm new to ignite but if it's an array, and the column names are random strings, I don't think that we can access an array in that way. cache.get(row)['foo'] won't work.

Comment: I recommend having a mapping of column id to column name somewhere, and index this array by column id. This unless your matrix is sparse, e.g, there are >10:1 unfilled columns to filled.

Answer (score 0):

From a thin client perspective, Ignite caches are flat, not nested. You can put arrays, sequences, dictionaries, or any combinations of above as a value in Ignite cache, but you can not traverse values inside the cache afterwards. You can only retrieve the whole value and look into it.

`cache.get(row)[column]` will work, but it will retrieve the whole row of 50000 elements from the cache as a Python list, and then address the single element in this list. I think in your case it will be sub-optimal.

If I got your question right, JSON-oriented databases (like MongoDB or PostgreSQL's JSONB) have the features you describe. Don't know if they are fast enough for data analysis though.